# Unity3D finding object in rectangle

Tags: unity-game-engine, cursor

I want to get all objects between two points (in a rectangle). It should be relative to the net, not to the screen. I don't want to check every object in game if is in rectangle.

What I want to make in two perspectives below. Green points are mouse position before and after.
Sorry for my bad english.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have 2D array of GameObjects which represent each object

```
objects = new GameObject[sizeX][sizeY];
```

Then you would need to get the indexes of two clicked object (not sure how you want to determine this, you can make bunch of colliders for each object then use OnMouseDown and raycasting, or Unity's built in check for if the object is clicked, or just determine which object is clicked based on mouse position and hard coded values of where objects are).

After you get indexes for two clicked objects each object between those two indexes is member of rectangle. The problem is that you are not sure in what direction should the loop go (eg. you clicked 1st object then 5th object and loop for that axis goes ++, but if you clicked 5th and then 1st then loop goes --).

We determine the direction like this:

```
int indexX1;
int indexY1;
int indexX2;
int indexY2;
int dirX;
int dirY;

if(indexX1 > indexX2) dirX = 1; else dirX = -1;
if(indexY1 > indexY2) dirY = 1; else dirY = -1;

for(int i = indexX1; i * dirX < indexX2 * dirX; i+=dirX){
   for(int j = indexY1; i * dirY < indexY2 * dirY; i+=dirY){
      //your code goes here
   }
}
```

This thing with dir works because of mathematical term:

x > y

-x < -y

eg.

5 > 3|

-5 < -3

Comment: But the biggest problem is that I must check position of every object in game all the time I want to draw rectangle like that :/ Maybe I should divide the world to chunks or something, so checking everything will not be neccessary.